# Autofac and IHttpClientFactory: Cannot resolve parameter 'System.Net.Http.HttpClient httpClient'

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, autofac

I'm building a console app and I decide to use Autofac following the example detailed [here](https://www.thecodebuzz.com/configure-httpclientfactory-autofac-di-httpclient/).

So I:

Registered the Autofac Service Provider

```
...
.UseServiceProviderFactory(new AutofacServiceProviderFactory())
...
```

Registerd the `IHttpClientFactory`:

```
containerBuilder
    .Register(ctx => ctx.Resolve<IHttpClientFactory>().CreateClient())
    .As<HttpClient>();
```

Registered all the other services, in particular:

```
containerBuilder.RegisterType<UpdaterServiceClient>().As<IUpdaterServiceClient>();
```

The `UpdaterServiceClient` has a constructor like this:

```
public UpdaterServiceClient(SBMOptions sbmOptions, IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory, ILogger<UpdaterServiceClient> logger)
```

The exception I obtain is:

> Type: Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException Message: An exception was thrown while activating UpdaterServiceClient.
> Type: Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException Message: None of the constructors found with 'Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.DefaultConstructorFinder' on type 'UpdaterServiceClient' can be invoked with the available services and parameters:
> Cannot resolve parameter 'System.Net.Http.IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory' of constructor 'Void .ctor(SBMOptions, System.Net.Http.IHttpClientFactory, Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger`1[UpdaterServiceClient])'.

Any suggestions as to what may be causing the issue

Comment: The example in the article is wrong. There seems to be a misconception as to what `ctx => ctx.Resolve<IHttpClientFactory>().CreateClient()` is actually doing. It appears to be registering `HttpClient` and not `IHttpClientFactory` which would explain what the container has no knowledge of the type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The example in the article is wrong. There seems to be a misconception as to what

```
containerBuilder
    .Register(ctx => ctx.Resolve<IHttpClientFactory>().CreateClient())
    .As<HttpClient>();
```

is actually doing.

It appears to be registering `HttpClient` and not `IHttpClientFactory` which would explain why the container has no knowledge of the type.

I suggest refactoring to add/configure the factory via the default extension and then using the 3rd party service provider.

Based on the article, it would look like this.

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) => {
            services.AddHttpClient(); //<-- ADD IHttpClientFactory AND RELATED SERVICES
        })
        .UseServiceProviderFactory(new AutofacServiceProviderFactory())
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder => {
            webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
        });
```

When `UseServiceProviderFactory` is invoked above, everything that was already added to the default `ServiceCollection` will be populated over to the Autofac Service Provider